# Possible to refactor this if/else statement with lots of string scans?

Tags: ruby, if-statement, refactoring

I'm trying to reduce the following if/else statement...

```
event_description = "We have a record of item FJ750701138GB as being delivered from Northampton North DO on 2013-08-10."
time = Time.now.strftime("%H:%M")

if date = event_description.scan(/We have a record of item [^>]* as being delivered from [^>]* on ([^<]*)./i).join
  datetime = Date.strptime("#{date} #{time}","%Y-%m-%d %H:%M").to_time
elsif date = event_description.scan(/Your item with reference [^>]* was delivered from our [^>]* Delivery Office on ([^<]*) ./i).join
  datetime = Date.strptime("#{date} #{time}","%d/%m/%y %H:%M").to_time
elsif date = event_description.scan(/Item [^>]* was collected and signed for by the addressee on the ([^<]*) from [^>]*/i).join
  datetime = Date.strptime("#{date} #{time}","%Y-%m-%d %H:%M").to_time
elsif date = event_description.scan(/Your item, posted on [^>]* with reference [^>]* was delivered in [^>]* on ([^<]*)./i).join
  datetime = Date.strptime("#{date} #{time}","%d/%m/%y %H:%M").to_time
end

event.occurred_at = datetime
```

The primary function of this is to scan various strings, pull the date out of it, and create a Date object.

- The dates can be in different formats (as you can see in the `striptime` instances)
- Over time, we'll be adding more `elsif` statements as we expand the strings we're scanning, so hoping to condense this a bit so it's not so bulky.

There's a relatively decent amount of code repetition, so trying to figure out how to refactor it a bit.

Comment: How about a regex to search for the date/time format?

Comment: In the given code, none of the `elsif`s is ever reached.

Comment: @Stefan I think he is giving an example of an `event_description`, not providing exact code.

Comment: @screenmutt yes, but `"any_string".scan(/any regex/).join` always returns a string, i.e. a truthy value.

Comment: Stefan is correct, and that is the point of my answer.

Comment: I recant and mourn in sackcloth in ashes.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the best option is to parse through the lines for the date and time formats that you want.

Something like this.

```
case description
when /(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})/
  puts year  = $1
  puts month = $2
  puts day   = $3
when /(\d{2})\/(\d{2})\/(\d{2})/
  puts day   = $1
  puts month = $2
  puts year  = $3
else
  puts "Unknown Date/Time"
end
```

And then use the variables to convert to your time.

Comment: That would almost work, except some strings will have two dates in them and there's a specific one I need.

Comment: It's not very awesome, but you could adjust the order of your `when` conditions to match which date you need first.

Answer (score 0):

`String#scan` will return an array, and doing `join` on the result will give a string, so **the first condition in your code will always be satisfied**.

*If this is on purpose*, you can drop the other condition and your code can be refactored to this:

```
event_description = "We have a record of item FJ750701138GB as being delivered from Northampton North DO on 2013-08-10."
date = event_description.scan(/We have a record of item [^>]* as being delivered from [^>]* on ([^<]*)./i).join
time = Time.now.strftime("%H:%M")
datetime = Date.strptime("#{date} #{time}","%Y-%m-%d %H:%M").to_time
event.occurred_at = datetime
```

Comment: Your answer ignores that I have multiple strings to take in to account...the whole purpose behind the if/else statement.

Comment: I have no idea about the purpose behind your conditions, but my code is equivalent to your code.

Comment: It's not. Like I mentioned in my post, there are different date formats to take in to account and if you look inside the if/else statements, you'll see the `strptime` accounts for both `YYYY-MM-DD` formats and `DD/MM/YY` (and in the future will support other date formats)

Comment: There are also entirely different strings to account for (again, as mentioned in my post). There's no way to just ignore the entire if/else block.

Comment: Pass in the string `Item JA105541368GB was collected and signed for by the addressee on the 2013-05-08 from Banbury DO.` to your code and tell me that still works.

Comment: I'm confused man. The code I have above *is* me doing that myself. I'm accounting for different strings and pulling the date out. And I'm asking how to condense all of that code. And right now, your response is to throw out the if/else statement. Or at least that what it sounds like.

Comment: @Shpigford: sawa is pointing out that your code is flawed in that only deals correctly with the first case, because the empty string `''` satisfies the first condition when there is no match. Although that is probably an aside to the purpose of the question, thus this is not an answer, but should help you fix your code

Comment: @NeilSlater Ahhh, I see what you're saying. And you're correct...that's an aside and not the purpose of the question.

Comment: It is a refactoring of the OP's code. Refactoring is to simplify a piece of code without changing its function. If the question was asking for a refactor, then this is an answer.